# TensorFlow: defining variables in global scope

Tags: tensorflow

I'm building an image classifier in TensorFlow, and there is a class imbalance in my training data. Therefore, when computing the loss, I need to weight the loss for each class by the inverse frequency of that class in the training data.

So, here is my code:

```
# Get the softmax from the final layer of the network
softmax = tf.nn.softmax(final_layer)
# Weight the softmax by the inverse frequency of the weights
weighted_softmax = tf.mul(softmax, class_weights)
# Compute the cross entropy
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(softmax))
# Define the optimisation
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-5).minimize(cross_entropy)

# Run the training
session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(10000):
  # Get the next batch
  batch = datasets.train.next_batch(64)
  # Run a training step
  train_step.run(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
```

My question is: Can I store `class_weights` as just a `tf.constant(...)` in global scope? Or do I need to pass it as a parameter when computing `cross_entropy`?

The reason I am wondering is that `class_weights` is different for every batch. Therefore, I am worried that if it is just defined in global scope, then when the Tensor Flow graph is constructed, it just takes the initial values in `class_weights`, and then never updates them. Whereas if I were to pass `class_weights` using the `feed_dict` when computing `weighted_softmax`, then I am explicitly telling Tensor Flow to use the recent, updated values in `class_weights`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think having `class_weights` a tf.constant is fine. Class weighting should be done for the whole dataset, not per mini-batch.

Also another approach to this you might want to consider is sampling so each batch has equal numbers of each class?

Comment: If I'm going ahead with having minibatches with unbalanced classes, should I still weight by the global class statistics? I would have thought it made sense to weight by the class statistics within that minibatch...? The gradients computed are for that minibatch only, and so they should not care about the global class statistics...

Comment: You make a good point. One thing is that as the mini batches are sampled from the wider class distribution. If you were to weight by mini batch that weight would converge to the weight of the wider distribution over a full iteration any way. So I think given that it is more efficient to only compute class_weights once. I wish I could find some kind of citation for this, but so far can't...